# Referenced table not found in the data dictionary mariadb

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, foreign-keys, heidisql

so I have written this Mariadb code as the solution for an assignment and am running it on HeidiSQL. It should work in theory however I am getting the error message SQL Error (1005): Can't create table bestellung.arbeitetin (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"). Upon using show warning, the program elaborates that "referenced table bestellung.arbeitetin not found in the data dictionary". I am wondering, is there something wrong with the code?

````
Datum date not NULL,
Abholtermin DATE,
Kostenstelle int not NULL,
Abteilung char(5) not NULL,
Mitarbeiter int not NULL,
Telefon int not NULL,
primary key (Bestellnummer)
);

create table enthaelt (
FK_Bestellnummer int not NULL,
FK_Artikelnummer char(10) not NULL,
Menge int not NULL,
unique key (FK_Bestellnummer, FK_Artikelnummer)
);

alter table enthaelt ADD
constraint FK_ArtikelNr
foreign key (FK_Artikelnummer)
references Artikel (Artikelnummer);

alter table enthaelt ADD
constraint FK_BestellNr
foreign key (FK_Bestellnummer)
references Bestellung (Bestellnummer);

create table arbeitetin
(
FK_PersNr int not NULL,
FK_ProjektNr int not NULL,
unique key(FK_PersNr, FK_ProjektNr)
);

alter table arbeitetin ADD 
    constraint FK_ARBEITETIN_MITARBEITER1 
        FOREIGN KEY (FK_PersNr) 
            REFERENCES Mitarbeiter (PersNr);

alter table arbeitetin ADD
    constraint FK_ARBEITETIN_PROJEKT
        foreign key (FK_ProjektNr)
            references Projekt (ProjektNr);

alter table Mitarbeiter ADD
    constraint FK_MITARBEITER_ABTEILUNG
        foreign key (FK_Abkuerzung)
            references Abteilung (Abkuerzung); ```
````